# how can id make Json query in mongo db C# driver for finding data

Tags: c#, mongodb

i use mongodb driver in C# for finding and ... records. i want to use json string query to find records. 
the below line is my code for finding the data.

```
var res = collection.Find<object>("{ longitude:49.3815270248724 }").ToList();
```

but i have an error on this line with this text: "MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'Unknown discriminator value 'record'.'"

but i test this query in "studio 3T for MongoDB". and i can fetch records in "Studio". my query in "studio ..." is:  `db.records.find({longitude:49.3815270248724})`

what can i do for this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these

Finding by filter (full method):

```
// Coordinate is a class
public async Task<List<Coordinate>> Get(double longitude)
{         
    var filter = new BsonDocument("longitude", longitude);
    var list = await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

    return list;
}
```

Filter record by Where Keyword:

```
var list = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(e => e.longitude == 49.3815270248724)        
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i did like "Finding by Filter" but i have the same error: ""